# What does the theoretical crosscorrelation function look like for two unrelated random walks?

Tags: correlation, econometrics, autocorrelation

What does the theoretical crosscorrelation function look like for two unrelated random walks? I know that for two random walks, they will be spuriously correlated. But what about the autocorrelations?

Comment: Not sure that I understand. Do you mean the cross-correlation function? The autocorrelation function relates one portion of a time series (or process) to its past.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. It has been corrected

Comment: Do you have reasons to believe that it would "look like" anything else but the constant $0$? Remember, you are asking about the _theoretical_ cross-correlation, not any _estimated_ cross-correlation (which would be the one _possibly_ exhibiting the "spurious correlation" phenomenon).

Comment: A random walk will be serially correlated, so I'd expect it not to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

So that the question does not remain unanswered: the cross-correlation function is a linear function of covariance.
We have two random walks,
$$x_t = x_{t-1} + u_t = \sum_{i=0}^tu_i,\;\; y_t = y_{t-1} + \epsilon_t=\sum_{i=0}^t\epsilon_i$$
independent, with independent white noises as building blocks.
The covariance between any two instances of these two processes is

$$\text {Cov}\left(x_{t-s},\; y_{t-k}\right) = E[x_{t-s}y_{t-k}] - E[x_{t-s}]E[y_{t-k}]$$

The second term is zero, since the expected values of the processes are zero. The first term is
$$E[x_{t-s}y_{t-k}] = E\left[\left(\sum_{i=0}^{t-s}u_i\right)\left(\sum_{i=0}^{t-k}\epsilon_i\right)\right]$$

Since the two white noises are independent, they are also uncorrelated, so the expected value of the cross-product of any two instances of them will be zero, $E[u_{t-s}\epsilon_{t-k}]=0,\; \forall t,s,k$. Hence the covariance is zero, the cross-correlation is zero, and the cross-correlation function is the constant $0$.

Comment: Does the mean of a random walk exist?

Comment: It does. If the random walk is defined as starting in the infinite past, then its expected value is an infinite sum of zeros (zero being the mean of the white-noise building block)-and in probability theory this equals zero. If it has started at some finite point in time, its mean obviously exists, and will equal the arbitrarily chosen "initial value" of the process (which is usually set equal to zero).